# What is the correct way of providing header-filter for clang-tidy in Cmake?

Tags: c++, cmake, clang, clang-tidy

I have projects that sets Clang-tidy configuration as following

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_CLANG_TIDY "clang-tidy;-checks=google-*,cppcoreguidelines-*;")
```

However, I have noticed that it was checking all the files that are not even in the current repo like

```
/opt/ros/melodic/include/ros/console.h
```

and all the .h/.hpp files of submodules...

I tried to add a regex to filter the target .h files but couldn't get it working...
I have given absolute path for a single .hpp file but it was still evaluating `/opt/ros/melodic/include` files...

Can I have an example on header-filter??

I assume clang-tidy will check the corresponding cpp file if hpp is in the filter. am I correct?

Comment: This might be a little bit late but since I got today a link to this question with a "Can we implement it this way?" question, I'll answer shortly... It doesn't work. Not even a little bit... -_- Apparently, clang-tidy uses for the regex ERE POSIX, which doesn't support lookarounds and not contained pattern checks. This is also mentioned in [another Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44111271/exclude-pattern-in-a-grep-using-extended-regex). There is currently an open ticket in the LLVM community (for almost 4 years) to handle this topic ([see here](https://reviews.llvm

Comment: ^ Correct link for the LLVM community open ticket: https://reviews.llvm.org/D34654

Answer (score 5):

You can look at this example. That's my commit. https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/pull/19928

This is how I disabled clang-tidy checks on two directories with regular expressions.

```
'^((?!/cocos2d-x/external/|/cocos/scripting/).)*$'
```

It disables clang-tidy checks on `external` directory and `cocos/scripting` directory.

I create a python script to test whether the regular expression is working as intended.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import re

files = [ 
"/home/john/cocos2d-x/external/openssl/include/linux/openssl/bio.h",
"/home/john/cocos2d-x/external/tiff/include/linux/tiff.h",
"/home/john/git/cocos/cocos2d-x/cocos/scripting/lua-bindings/auto/lua_cocos2dx_3d_auto.cpp"
"/home/john/cocos2d-x/external/json/stringbuffer.h",
"/home/john/cocos2d-x/cocos/base/ccUtils.h",
"/home/john/git/cocos/cocos2d-x/cocos/scripting/js-bindings/precheader.cpp",
"/home/john/cocos2d-x/cocos/physics/CCPhysicsBody.cpp",
"/home/john/cocos2d-x/tests/cpp-tests/Classes/ActionsEaseTest/ActionsEaseTest.cpp",
"/home/john/cocos2d-x/templates/cpp-template-default/Classes/AppDelegate.cpp",
"/home/john/git/cocos/cocos2d-x/cocos/scripting/js-bindings/proj.android/CMakeLists.txt",
]

pattern = '^((?!/cocos2d-x/external/|/cocos/scripting/).)*$'

for file in files:
    m = re.search(pattern, file)
    if m:
        print m.group(0)
```

Running this python file and the output is

```sh
/home/john/cocos2d-x/cocos/base/ccUtils.h
/home/john/cocos2d-x/cocos/physics/CCPhysicsBody.cpp
/home/john/cocos2d-x/tests/cpp-tests/Classes/ActionsEaseTest/ActionsEaseTest.cpp
/home/john/cocos2d-x/templates/cpp-template-default/Classes/AppDelegate.cpp
```

You can modify the regular expression and python test script to see if it works.

Comment: With which tidy version did you do this? My similar one worked with clang-tidy-6, but doesnt work for 9+.

Comment: BASH doesn't support "lookaround" (lookahead and lookbehind) and I'm pretty sure that clang-tidy uses a bash regex.

Comment: Can confirm as of latest LLVM December 2022, this is still wrong. It will ignore those headers, but it actually silently ignores ALL the headers because the regex is invalid! It works in Python, but won't work in LLVM's clang-tidy: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71797349/is-it-possible-to-ignore-a-header-with-clang-tidy

Answer (score 3):

The following is a minimal C++ code doing an equivalent of what is going on in clang-tidy in terms of headers filter processing.

```
#include <llvm/Support/Regex.h>
#include <llvm/ADT/StringRef.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char**)
{
  llvm::StringRef re_str = R"(my_fancy_regex_string_goes_here)";
  llvm::Regex re(re_str);
  if(not re.isValid())
  {
    std::cout << "invalid regex" << std::endl;
    return -1;
  }

  llvm::StringRef file_str = "path_to_the_problematic_file";
  if(not re.match(file_str)){
    std::cout << "does not match" << std::endl;
  } else {
    std::cout << "matches" << std::endl;
  }
}
```

I'm compiling it as follows (MacOS 12.0.1):

```
clang++  llvm_re_test.cpp  $(llvm-config --cxxflags --ldflags --libs --system-libs)
```

Once your regex works fine with such minimalistic code it will work fine with clang-tidy.

Comment: I got `fatal error: 'llvm/Support/Regex.h' file not found`

Comment: what's the output of llvm-config? I've got:
`llvm-config --cxxflags --ldflags --libs --system-libs
-I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/llvm/17.0.6_1/include -std=c++17 -stdlib=libc++   -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS
-L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/llvm/17.0.6_1/lib -Wl,`